# Deeplink on amp-accordion

Tags: accordion, deep-linking, amp-html

I would like to deeplink into an amp website. Is it possible to link into an accordion menu content?

I could not find any information about that.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727657/deep-link-and-open-an-accordion-item)? It also uses deep link in `amp-accordion`.

Comment: There are many solutions published on jquery accordions, but I can´t find any way with Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)